# Constexpr: Comparision to nullptr - Bug or feature?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, constexpr

GCC is unable to evaluate some expression as constant. Clang however is nice with it.

```
/*
 */
constexpr int foo(const int * array)
{
  if (array == nullptr) // Error: '(((const int*)(& array)) == 0u)' is not a constant expression
  {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

constexpr int bar()
{
  int array[100] = {};

  return foo(array);
}

static_assert(bar() == 1, "outch..."); // Does not compile. See above.
static_assert(foo(nullptr) == 0, "okay");

constexpr int i[100] = {};
static_assert(foo(i) == 1, "okay");
```

Does also not work:

```
constexpr int foobar()
{
  int array[100] = {};
  int *ar = array;
  if (ar == nullptr) // Error...
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

static_assert(foobar() == 1, "okay");
```

Same thing:

```
constexpr int foo2()
{ 
  int *a = nullptr;
  if (a == nullptr) // Error...
  {
    return 0;
  } 
  return 1;
}

static_assert(foo2() == 0, "okay");
```

[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g540,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez:PQKgUABFUsYMYHsB2BnALgUwB4AcBOEAlsuhAGaKIAUSaZJZIEAhvviwJ4CUYA3pGLkI1Nh04QAvJIjIArgBsFudPl5QB0CPkzo5%2BZBAAMAbkEBfMIJ16DEAIxnLCFBhwFipCACM21XpqeZGJcANr2RkYAulIQfOZm1rr6hpQ0ITxOVhgs6ETwAPosqKiY%2BOjUvvj%2BUjL2ADQQAESIANZcTdxmOXmFxaXl1GnU8koqarXGjS3tnJ2JdG54hIzE4ZExMvHd6Ln5RSVlFcNE3JMNzW0dXVagkLAu9O4rXmlV/vyCqxnr0bHbVigLDk6EQrEIMgyiSgRGEoghMlGylU6jigigNhSxjMUEsGOSdkcYGcPX2/SOQyo7zO0gc0yucxudwgD0WWGWQQoVAATB8%2BBAvl4QCxYkjxjihCIRbSxSjBIF8bZDKYLALFViiSTdr0DgNjjyarSjPTZvMgAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

I mean, a comparison to `nullptr` should be something else than a comparison to an other random address.

Would you say: it is a bug or a matter of interpretation? For me, it is difficult to write the same code for both compilers...

This error happens for GCC 5.0 to 5.4. In GCC 6+ only `foobar()` does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already fixed for gcc-7. I've opened:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77539
to request a backport.